# How to Write Files or Folder to IPFS via the HTTP API

Tags: http, go, ipfs

I'm confused about the HTTP API docs of IPFS。next is part of it。

/api/v0/add
Add a file or directory to IPFS.
//but how to add a directory by golang? it look like so simple but no a example to finish it

#cURL Example
curl -X POST -F file=@myfile "http://127.0.0.1:5001/api/v0/add?quiet=&quieter=&silent=&progress=&trickle=&only-hash=&wrap-with-directory=&chunker=size-262144&pin=true&raw-leaves=&nocopy=&fscache=&cid-version=&hash=sha2-256&inline=&inline-limit=32"

Comment: TheHTTP API docs of IPFS  in https://docs.ipfs.io/reference/http/api/#api-v0-add

Answer (score 1):

I worked on the same issue and found this working shell solution:

https://community.infura.io/t/ipfs-http-api-add-directory/189/8

you can rebuild this in go

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "mime/multipart"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "testing"
)

func TestUploadFolderRaw(t *testing.T) {
    ct, r, err := createForm(map[string]string{
        "/file1": "@/my/path/file1",
        "/dir": "@/my/path/dir",
        "/dir/file": "@/my/path/dir/file",
    })
    assert.NoError(t, err)

    resp, err := http.Post("http://localhost:5001/api/v0/add?pin=true&recursive=true&wrap-with-directory=true", ct, r)
    assert.NoError(t, err)

    respAsBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    assert.NoError(t, err)

    t.Log(string(respAsBytes))
}

func createForm(form map[string]string) (string, io.Reader, error) {
    body := new(bytes.Buffer)
    mp := multipart.NewWriter(body)
    defer mp.Close()
    for key, val := range form {
        if strings.HasPrefix(val, "@") {
            val = val[1:]
            file, err := os.Open(val)
            if err != nil { return "", nil, err }
            defer file.Close()
            part, err := mp.CreateFormFile(key, val)
            if err != nil { return "", nil, err }
            io.Copy(part, file)
        } else {
            mp.WriteField(key, val)
        }
    }
    return mp.FormDataContentType(), body, nil
}
```

or use https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs-http-client which seems to be a better way. I'm working on it and tell you when I know how to use it

Greetings